# Python While loops with tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function which should count the numbers in an inputted phrase. That phrase gets stored as a tuple and the while loop should count the number of vowels. So far I have gotten this.

```
def whilephrase():
    vowels=['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u']
    print('Please give me a phrase')
    inputphrase=input()
    inputphrase=tuple(inputphrase)
    i=0
    while True:
        if vowels in inputphrase:
            i=i+1
        else:
            print(i)
```

But this just prints out an endless loop of zeros.

Comment: endless loop? `while True` will cause that...

Comment: Also use a set instead of a list, when you are looking for items. You could just say vowels = set(vowels)

Comment: @shravster - that is a minor performance difference and doesn't address the problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over your inputphrase:

```
for character in inputphrase:
    if character in vowels:
        i = i + 1
print(i)
```

But there is, of course, an easier way:

```
def count_vowels(string):
    return sum(1 for c in string if c.lower() in "aeiou")
```

**edit:** Using a while loop (although I'm not sure why you want specifically that):

```
index = 0
i = 0
while index < len(inputphrase):
    if inputphrase[index] in vowels:
        i += 1
    index += 1
print(i)
```

Comment: I know that using a for loop would work but is there any way to use a while loop?

Comment: @MatthewGaray I don't know why you would want that, but sure, see edit.

Comment: **while** is not particularly appropriate here.  When you get into the loop, you know exactly how many times you need to go through it.  The exit condition is not dependent on what's inside the loop.  That makes **for** the proper choice.

Comment: The edited **while** loop will throw an exception when **index** gets to the length of **inputphrase**.

Comment: @Prune What are you talking about? It works fine for me.

Comment: Never mind.  I apparently saw an intermediate version that still had **while True** at the top.

Comment: No lambda needed. Do `sum(1 for c in inputphrase if c.lower() in 'aeiou')`

Answer (score 2):

```
print len([i for i in inputphrase if i in vowels])
```

Comment: `sum(inputphrase.count(x) for x in vowels)`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `collections`

```
from collections import Counter
sum([Counter(inputphrase)[i] for i in vowels])
```

Comment: this sums all vowels in inputphrase, but the other solutions counts number of occurences, so maybe I just misunderstood the problem...

Comment: @innoSPG This is clearly an answer. It may be wrong or incomplete, but it is an answer. If it is wrong, down vote it. Please utilize the review queue properly and delete only things that are not answers.

Comment: @Andy, I was wrong by judging to quickly; with an answer that start as "you can also use `collection`", it is easy to missjudge without paying enough attention. Sorry Juraj. Please make sure to not make your answer so weak with such introduction. I deleted the comment.